# Git Repo Creation Visual Studio 2019 Fails

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When an attempt is made to use File 
Add to Source Control
it fails.  Microsoft Visual Studio 2019
Git error message states the some files are outside the solution.  I cannot find such files after inspection.  I looked at the directories listed in the properties.

The source code compiles and executes.  The original source code is from [many] years ago.  The source files are at the same level as the solution files.

More recently created projects seem to repeat a subordinate directory name for the source files.

Such as Z:\blah1\blah2\newname\newname

I attempted to move solution project files to a parent directory.  VS2019 identifies files as missing or moved.  So naively moving files is not a solution.

Git operates successfully for other more recently created projects.

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: `Such as Z:\blah1\blah2\newname\newname` That would happen if you create a new project with "*place solution and project in the same directory*" not checked.